# How to set a Http header to retrive a json Object

Tags: android, json

Im trying to create a httpGet that returns a similar request as :

http://www.myserver.com/do.json?json={"magazine":"-1"}

I can't seem to get the header right though....
I tried :

```
    url = "http://www.myserver.com/do.json";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    //httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpGet.addHeader("magazine", "-1");

    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this properly ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        HttpGet get;
        HttpParams httpParameters;
try
            {
                httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
                        (username + ":" + userpwd).getBytes("UTF-8"), 
                        android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP
                    );
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(StaticURL.uMain+resourceURI);

                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ auth);

                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                response = client.execute(request);
                userAuth = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                System.out.println("Data. in login.."+userAuth);


            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {

                System.out.println("Error.."+e);
            }
```

note: use Base64 api externally

Comment: Sorry but i still dont get it. What do I have to do to add this :     ?json={"magazine":"-1"} to my url when i do the request?

Comment: here u hav to use Namepairvalue using http entity search on google