# How to send Json object?

Tags: android, json, http

I am really new bee in android,so can anyone please help me to my problem...here is : I am using two AutoCompletedTextView as "username" and "password", So here I need to send the username and password as JSon Object for HTTP request.Now how do I bind username and password in Json object. Any help will really be appreciated THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to set a Http header to retrive a json Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814709/how-to-set-a-http-header-to-retrive-a-json-object/5814753#5814753)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code

```
Button show_data;
JSONObject my_json_obj;
String path,firstname,lastname;
path = "http://192.168.101.123:255/services/services.php?id=9";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
HttpEntity  entity;
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpURLConnection urlconn;
my_json_obj = new JSONObject();
try
{
    urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
    urlconn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    urlconn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

my_json_obj.put("sUserName", "test2"); my_json_obj.put("sPassword", "123456");

writer.write(my_json_obj.toString()); writer.close();

if(true) { String temp; temp = WebRequestCall(my_json_obj); //Log.i("Reply", temp); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send  Json object to server using

```
JSONObject jsonObjRecv = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
```

and `HttpClient class` is

```
public class HttpClient {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";

    public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

            StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

            // Set HTTP parameters
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

            // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // Read the content stream
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                }

                // convert content stream to a String
                String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
                resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

                // Transform the String into a JSONObject
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
                // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
                Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

                return jsonObjRecv;
            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
            // For now we just print the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         * 
         * (c) public domain: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```