# How to set authentication while using JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I am using JSON for parsing data in android.
 I have a JSON URL which requires username and password for authentication. I just went through the below tutorial for implementing JSON.

[JSON implmentation](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

It is easy to implement but in my application i need to send the username and password for authentication. I am bit confused about this.

Can anyone please tell me how to set Content-Type, accept, Authorization in JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Sorry. i cant share the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to HTTP authentication, not JSON authentication. 
Refer this link to see [how to make HTTP Connections in Android.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) This is the code snippet for you to authenticate using normal HTTP authentication.

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

   });
 }
```

[This](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/rest-api-with-http-authentication-android-beanstalk-example/) is example using HTTPClient.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814753/1234007) is another code snippet that deals with adding HTTP headers, the way you want.

Clarity of the question is in direct proportion with the accuracy and precision of the answer. Being little clearer will be better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ i use it for Json and more and is simple to use

Comment: Is there any other way to set Authorization without using the library.

Comment: this user and pass i image is stored in a DB right?..you must create a post request, and response in Json